# Can we send NgRx devtools logging to custom logger

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an NgRx enabled application (currently Angular 7) where I setup the StoreDevTools as follows:

```
 StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  name: `MyApp DevTools`,
  maxAge: 25,
  logOnly: environment.production,
}),
```

My app has a custom logger that sends details to a custom location (not the console).

My question is, can I also get the NgRx logging to call my own logging function when logOnly is set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logOnly` has the value from `environment.production`, so you can check your condition based on `environment.production` value (if you are sure, that you will assign `environment.production` to `logOnly`).

Here is an example of simple logger based on `environment.production` condition:

```
function ownLogger(state, action) {
  console.log(state, action);
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MyCounterComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      name: 'NgRx Demo App',
      logOnly: environment.production,
      monitor: (state, action) => {
        console.log(environment);
        if (environment.production) {
          ownLogger(state, action);
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image: NGRX logs]

[**An example (Angular 9)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-95pdnw?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: Thankyou! That is exactly what I was after. In my case `state` always seems to be undefined, but that is ok as it is the action I want to log.